# Mongoose populate function not working after .find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to query out multiple user profiles and then populate each one of the profiles and send it to the client side of my web application. But it's failing miserably. I have done my research and tried everything but it still won't populate it. Here's my axios request to my backend :

```
router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
errors = {}

Profile.find().populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
    .then(profiles => {
        if (!profiles) {
            errors.noprofile = " there are no profiles"
            res.status(404).json(errors)
        }
        else {
            res.json(profiles)
        }
    }).catch(err => res.json(errors))

})
```

Here user property of the profile isn't populating and i am getting just a user id in my profile collection. I have used findOne({user:req.user.id}) to fetch a particular user and then populate it using populate('user',['name','avatar']) above in my file and it has worked absolutely fine.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: It doesn't contain a solution to my problem, I have already gone through it.

Comment: ['name', 'avatar'] <-- are these fields from the profile document?

Answer (score 1):

Following code may be work, in **path** option it should be your field name which is available in your profile schema and in **model** option the name of model which is reference model schema

```
router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
        errors = {}

        Profile.find({})
            .populate({
                path: 'user',
                model: 'user',
                select: 'name avatar',
            })
            .exec(function (err, profiles) {
                if (err) {
                    errors.noprofile = " there are no profiles"
                    res.status(404).json(errors)
                } else {
                    res.json(profiles)
                }
            });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.populate()` needs a query to attach itself to, try `.find({})`